# Parsing constraints as string to scipy constraints

Tags: python, scipy

I would be need to define constraints of the Scipy Optimisation library in text form using mathematical notations. Does there exist any library or published code which would allow me to do this?

For example,

```
x[0] < sin(x[1]) + 1.9
```

becomes,

```
from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint
import numpy as np
con = lambda x: x[0] - np.sin(x[1])
nlc = NonlinearConstraint(con, -np.inf, 1.9)
```

Comment: Remember that these `NonlinearConstraint`s are objects and you are going to have to use these with other methods such as `minimize` from `scipy.optimize`.  Thus, even if you write a parser for strings like `"x[0] < sin(x[1]) + 1.9"`, the parser would have to return a `NonlinearConstraint` object, which makes no difference.

Comment: Yes this is clear to me. I was hoping to use this parsing as I am building a framework which shall allow users to tweak parameters without having to declare implementation specific objects.

Comment: Use sympy. It has direct support for expression parsing and can generate a Callable.